Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, startDate, days, absenceType, employee, approved})
I am trying to map through some data I have received from an API  but I keep getting this error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, startDate, days, absenceType, employee, approved}).
Now I have tried to map through it, I have tried to use Object, flatMap and forEach nothing seems to work. It looks like its an array of objects, am I missing something here? I just want to display this data on the page.
I have attached a screenshot of what the data looks like.
UPDATE: Following some advice my code looks like this now:
{Object.entries(absence).map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      {" "}
      <p>ID: {item.id}</p> <p>Start Date: {item.startDate}</p>{""}
      <p>Days: {item.days}</p>{" "}
    </div>
 }


However the data is still not showing.
Update 2.0: Definately made improvements however some entries look empty and also tried to access the first and last name and it wont let me.
{Object.entries(absence.absence).map((item) =>
    item.map((i) => (
      <div key={i.id}>
        {" "}
        <p>ID: {i.id}</p> <p>Start Date: {i.startDate}</p>{" "}
        <p>Days: {i.days}</p>
        <p>absenceType: {i.absenceType}</p>
        <p>Status: {i.approved}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  )}



Don't past images of code. Take the the time to type out or paste sample data as well as the minimal code required to reproduce the problem. This will help both with readability and improve the answers you receive. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

First absence is an object. Within it another absence exists which contains an array of objects. Use absence.absence.forEach((elm)=>elm).

I have already tried that it gives me this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
{absence.absence.forEach((i) => (
{i}
))}

use map {absence.absence.map((item) => (

ID: {item.id}
Start Date: {item.startDate}
Days: {item.days}

))}

I think we are getting somewhere, but no data is showing yet, I have attached an image of what it looks like now on the post

Please take a look.

just use absence.absence.map. and look in second console. you getting array. which contain first 'absence ', then array of obj.. so try accessingtwo elm and map through it

I think we almost got it but its behaving in a weird way, it populated some data but it leaves some empty and I havent been able to access the first and last name

you are receiving the object of object
so i think you should try this
  {!!absence && absence?.absence?.length > 0 ? (
    absence?.absence.map((i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i.id}>
          <p>ID: {i.id}</p> <p>Start Date: {i.startDate}</p>{" "}
          <p>Days: {i.days}</p>
          <p>absenceType: {i.absenceType}</p>
          <p>Status: {i.approved}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <p>No data Found</p>
  )}

You have to and check like, iterate the data only if absence is present.
Hope it will work for you.
